# Table Not Created On All MySQL Masters

Tags: mysql, replication, table, multi-master

Here is the multi master setup.
Table is not created on middle master.

log-slave-updates is not enabled in my.cnf file.

Master 1

```
mysql> create database replication;
mysql> use replication;
mysql> CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT Not Null) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

Master 2

```
mysql> use replication;
mysql> select * from T1;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'replication.T1' doesn't exist
```

Master 3

```
mysql> use replication;
Database changed
mysql> select * from T1;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Questions: Q1) Which direction is Replication, is it `M1->M2->M3` and back to `M1`, or is it `M3->M2->M1` and back to `M3` ? Q2) When you run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';` on each Master, what values do you get ?

Comment: If `log_slave_updates` is not enabled in *any* of your my.cnf files, then the real question is not why M2 is wrong.  T1 was created separately on M1 and M3 (or why is there data on M3, which you don't show inserting it on M1?).  Multi-master requires `log_slave_updates` on every server.

Answer (score 0):

@Michaelsqlbot's comment makes it easy to see the issue

Replication must be going

```
+----<------------<-----+
|                       ^
|                       |
V                       |
+--> M3 -> M2-> M1 -->--+
```

or

```
+----<------------<-----+
|                       ^
|                       |
V                       |
+--> M1 -> M3-> M2 -->--+
```

and `M2` does not have `log-slave-updates`

Given that topology, here is the sequence of events that must have taken place

- You created table `T1` on `M1`
- `M3` has table `T1`
- `M2` does not have table `T1` because `M2` does not have `log-slave-updates`
- You inserted `2` into table `T1`

  - If the `INSERT` was done on `M1`, `M3` has data, `M2` has no data and no table `T1`
  - If the `INSERT` was done on `M3`, `M1` has no data, `M2` has no data and no table `T1`

## EPILOGUE

Configuring [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) tells a Slave to take a binlog event from its relay logs, execute it, and record the event in its local binlogs (if [log-bin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) is enabled on the Slave). Thus, `M2` not having [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) enabled in your MultiMaster setup is the root cause.

Big thanks to @Michaelsqlbot for the hint.